# How to print custom listview data in android

Tags: android

How to print custom listview data to printer when click print button in android. I have no experience about android print setting. How to implement printing service class.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/printservice/package-summary.html. look at docs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would require that you create a `PrintDocumentAdapter`.

Note that this is rather new functionality and will only work on API level 19 or greater. Previous version would require you to use [Google Cloud Printing](https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/docs/android).

More detail within the print [package summary](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/print/package-summary.html) and an [example for printing a custom document](http://developer.android.com/training/printing/custom-docs.html).

Comment: Does need Google Cloud Printing internet access? Can use over ethernet?